# gwt problem with HandlerRegistration

Tags: gwt, handlers

I have a problem. 
I have a map and added ClickHandler, but after pushing a button I want to remove it. I know that there's some HandlerRegistration but I don't know how to use it.
part of my code:

```
map.addMapClickHandler(new MapClickHandler()

        {
            public void onClick(MapClickEvent e) 
            {
                 ...
                }
        });
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: in the map is google map in which you can add points

Answer (score 0):

[MapWidget#addMapClickHandler()](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.1/com/google/gwt/maps/client/MapWidget.html#addMapClickHandler%28com.google.gwt.maps.client.event.MapClickHandler%29) doesn't return a HandlerRegistration, but the MapWidget class defines a [removeMapClickHandler() method](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.1/com/google/gwt/maps/client/MapWidget.html#removeMapClickHandler%28com.google.gwt.maps.client.event.MapClickHandler%29):

```
map.addMapClickHandler(new MapClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(MapClickEvent event) {
    // Make sure map is visible to this inner class. It needs
    // either to be a member of the enclosing class or final.
    map.removeMapClickHandler(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: there's an error: "type mismatch: cannot convert from void to HandlerRegistration"

Comment: You're right - I don't use the Maps API so I didn't actually test what I had written. The example in my answer should now work.

Comment: it still doesn't work. because i want to remove this handler after pushing the button which will show me the route (from previously added markers)

Comment: Can you be more specific as to why this solution doesn't work? If you need to call MapWidget#removeMapClickHandler() from somewhere else you can do so as long as you keep a reference to the MapClickHandler around.

Comment: ok, i handled it another way (without removing handler). anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need this, it took me a while to figure out the solution

```
final Set<HandlerRegistration> hack = new HashSet<HandlerRegistration>();
hack.add(map.addMapClickHandler(new MapClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(MapClickEvent e) {
        ...
        // remove handler here
        for (HandlerRegistration hr : hack) {
            hr.removeHandler();
        }
    }
}));
```