# GWT - cells values after Button ClickEvent in whole table the same

Tags: gwt

My GWT-project is a simple calendar. You can add a date by clicking on a table cell, which is opening a dialog to enter a name and the description.
The date will wrote to the tablecell, when you click on "OK" or cancel with "Abbrechen".
My code (build in Eclipse):

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DecoratorPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Grid;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLTable.Cell;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class ShowCase implements EntryPoint {
int a = 24; // Anzahl Zeit-Zeilen (Normalfall 24 -> 0:00 - 23:00)
int start = 7;
int end = 21;

DecoratorPanel panel = new DecoratorPanel();

Grid t = new Grid((a + 1), 8); //

String days[] = { " ", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag",
        "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag" };

String data = null, str1 = null, str2 = null;

DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
Grid dialoggrid = new Grid(3, 2); // Grid-Layout für gesamte DialogBox
Label lname = new Label("Name");
Label lbeschr = new Label("Beschreibung");
TextBox tbname = new TextBox();
TextBox tbbeschr = new TextBox();
Button ok = new Button("OK");
Button cancel = new Button("Abbrechen");

int indexrow, indexcol;

DialogBox leer = new DialogBox();
Button okleer = new Button("OK");

public void onModuleLoad() {
    t.setBorderWidth(1);
    t.setCellSpacing(0);
    for (int row = 0; row < (a + 1); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            if (col == 0) {
                int z = row - 1;
                System.out.println("Spalte 0 Zeit setzen: " + row);
                t.setText(row, col, z + ":00"); // Spalte 0 Zeit setzen
            } else {
                t.setText(row, col, "");
            }

            t.setText(0, col, days[col]); // Tage aus days in Zeile 0 setzen
            t.getCellFormatter().setWidth(row, 0, "50px");
            t.getCellFormatter().setWidth(row, col, "150px");
        }
    } // end for(int row=0...)

    panel.add(t);
    RootPanel.get("content").add(panel);

    t.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Neuer Klick!");
            Cell cell = ((HTMLTable) event.getSource()).getCellForEvent(event);
            System.out.println("Cell cell HTML Table");

            /*if (data.equals("1")){
                    tbname.setText(text);
                    tbbeschr.setText(null);
            }*/

            System.out.println("data1: " + data);
            // Uhrzeit-Spalte und Wochentagsreihe absichern
            if(!(cell.getRowIndex() == 0) && !(cell.getCellIndex() ==0)){
                System.out.println("Get Index(): " + cell.getRowIndex() + ","   + cell.getCellIndex());  // Ausgabe von Reihe und Spalte
                final int indexrow = cell.getRowIndex();
                final int indexcol = cell.getCellIndex();




                // Dialog belegen und anzeigen
                dialoggrid.setCellSpacing(0);
                dialoggrid.setCellPadding(0);

                tbname.setText(null);
                tbbeschr.setText(null);

                System.out.println("TBName: " + tbname.getText());
                System.out.println("TBBeschr: " +  tbbeschr.getText());

                dialoggrid.setWidget(0, 0, lname);
                dialoggrid.setWidget(1, 0, lbeschr);
                dialoggrid.setWidget(2, 0, ok);

                dialoggrid.setWidget(0, 1, tbname);
                dialoggrid.setWidget(1, 1, tbbeschr);
                dialoggrid.setWidget(2, 1, cancel);


                dialog.setWidget(dialoggrid);
                dialog.center();
                dialog.setModal(false);

                if(tbname.getText().equals(null)){
                    System.out.println("if tbname.getText equals null");
                }


                System.out.println("Dialog show");
                dialog.show();

                ok.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        System.out.println("ok Click");
                        // Überprüfen ob TextBox Name und Beschreibung nicht leer sind
                        if ((!tbname.getText().equals(null)) && (!tbbeschr.getText().equals(null))) {
                            System.out.println("Wenn tbname & tbbeschr nicht leer sind");
                            str1 = tbname.getText();
                            str2 = tbbeschr.getText();
                            data = str1 + ", " + str2;
                            t.setText(indexrow, indexcol, data);
                            dialog.hide();
                            System.out.println("#1: "+data+"#");
                            data = null;
                            System.out.println("#2: "+data+"#");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("leer!");
                            leer.setText("Felder duerfen nicht leer sein!");
                            leer.add(okleer);
                            leer.center();
                            leer.setModal(true);
                            leer.show();

                            okleer.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
                                public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
                                    System.out.println("okleer click");
                                    leer.hide();
                                }
                            });
                        } // end else

                    }
                }); // end ok.addClickHandler

                cancel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        System.out.println("cancel Click");
                        dialog.hide();
                        tbname.setText(null);
                        tbbeschr.setText(null);
                    }
                }); // end cancel.addClickHandler

            } // end if(!(cellindex) && !(rowindex) =0 )

        } // end public void OnClick()
    }); // end t.addClickHandler
} // end onModuleLoad(}
```

The problem is, that, by entering the name & description in the dialog and click "OK", it overwrites all clicked cells (also the canceled dialog cells) with the values from my current dialog. 
Some testcases with output in the console (by OK-Click it makes even more OK-Clicks for each clicked cell):

```
Neuer Klick!
Cell cell HTML Table
data1: null
Get Index(): 1,1
TBName: 
TBBeschr: 
Dialog show
ok Click
Wenn tbname & tbbeschr nicht leer sind
#1: rt, qw#
#2: null#
Neuer Klick!
Cell cell HTML Table
data1: null
Get Index(): 1,2
TBName: 
TBBeschr: 
Dialog show
ok Click
Wenn tbname & tbbeschr nicht leer sind
#1: gh, tz#
#2: null#
ok Click
Wenn tbname & tbbeschr nicht leer sind
#1: gh, tz#
#2: null#
```

Why? Or is there a better possibility to "manage" the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HandlerRegistration for your Click handler. As you are not clearing the the click handler, that is why it is calling the earlier events also..

Refer below links for further details:

[GWT HandlerRegistration](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/HandlerRegistration.html)

[similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715034/gwt-problem-with-handlerregistration)

It seems you are quite new to GWT. Here is the working solution:

package com.my.first.client;

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DecoratorPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Grid;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLTable.Cell;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class ShowCase implements EntryPoint {
    int a = 24; // Anzahl Zeit-Zeilen (Normalfall 24 -> 0:00 - 23:00)
    int start = 7;
    int end = 21;

    DecoratorPanel panel = new DecoratorPanel();

    Grid t = new Grid((a + 1), 8); //

    String days[] = { " ", "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag", "Sonntag" };

    String data = null, str1 = null, str2 = null;

    DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
    Grid dialoggrid = new Grid(3, 2); // Grid-Layout für gesamte DialogBox
    Label lname = new Label("Name");
    Label lbeschr = new Label("Beschreibung");
    TextBox tbname = new TextBox();
    TextBox tbbeschr = new TextBox();
    Button ok = new Button("OK");
    Button cancel = new Button("Abbrechen");

    HandlerRegistration okHandlerRegistration;

    int indexrow, indexcol;

    DialogBox leer = new DialogBox();
    Button okleer = new Button("OK");

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        t.setBorderWidth(1);
        t.setCellSpacing(0);
        for (int row = 0; row < (a + 1); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                if (col == 0) {
                    int z = row - 1;
                    System.out.println("Spalte 0 Zeit setzen: " + row);
                    t.setText(row, col, z + ":00"); // Spalte 0 Zeit setzen
                } else {
                    t.setText(row, col, "");
                }

                t.setText(0, col, days[col]); // Tage aus days in Zeile 0 setzen
                t.getCellFormatter().setWidth(row, 0, "50px");
                t.getCellFormatter().setWidth(row, col, "150px");
            }
        } // end for(int row=0...)

        panel.add(t);
        RootPanel.get("content").add(panel);

        t.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                System.out.println("Neuer Klick!");
                Cell cell = ((HTMLTable) event.getSource()).getCellForEvent(event);
                System.out.println("Cell cell HTML Table");

                /*
                 * if (data.equals("1")){ tbname.setText(text);
                 * tbbeschr.setText(null); }
                 */

                System.out.println("data1: " + data);
                // Uhrzeit-Spalte und Wochentagsreihe absichern
                if (!(cell.getRowIndex() == 0) && !(cell.getCellIndex() == 0)) {
                    System.out.println("Get Index(): " + cell.getRowIndex() + "," + cell.getCellIndex()); // Ausgabe
                                                                                                            // von
                                                                                                            // Reihe
                                                                                                            // und
                                                                                                            // Spalte
                    final int indexrow = cell.getRowIndex();
                    final int indexcol = cell.getCellIndex();

                    // Dialog belegen und anzeigen
                    dialoggrid.setCellSpacing(0);
                    dialoggrid.setCellPadding(0);

                    tbname.setText(null);
                    tbbeschr.setText(null);

                    System.out.println("TBName: " + tbname.getText());
                    System.out.println("TBBeschr: " + tbbeschr.getText());

                    dialoggrid.setWidget(0, 0, lname);
                    dialoggrid.setWidget(1, 0, lbeschr);
                    dialoggrid.setWidget(2, 0, ok);

                    dialoggrid.setWidget(0, 1, tbname);
                    dialoggrid.setWidget(1, 1, tbbeschr);
                    dialoggrid.setWidget(2, 1, cancel);

                    dialog.setWidget(dialoggrid);
                    dialog.center();
                    dialog.setModal(false);

                    if (tbname.getText().equals(null)) {
                        System.out.println("if tbname.getText equals null");
                    }

                    System.out.println("Dialog show");
                    dialog.show();

                    if (okHandlerRegistration != null) {
                        okHandlerRegistration.removeHandler();
                    }

                    okHandlerRegistration = ok.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                            System.out.println("ok Click");
                            // Überprüfen ob TextBox Name und Beschreibung nicht
                            // leer sind
                            if ((!tbname.getText().equals(null)) && (!tbbeschr.getText().equals(null))) {
                                System.out.println("Wenn tbname & tbbeschr nicht leer sind");
                                str1 = tbname.getText();
                                str2 = tbbeschr.getText();
                                data = str1 + ", " + str2;
                                t.setText(indexrow, indexcol, data);
                                dialog.hide();
                                System.out.println("#1: " + data + "#");
                                data = null;
                                System.out.println("#2: " + data + "#");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("leer!");
                                leer.setText("Felder duerfen nicht leer sein!");
                                leer.add(okleer);
                                leer.center();
                                leer.setModal(true);
                                leer.show();

                                okleer.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                                        System.out.println("okleer click");
                                        leer.hide();
                                    }
                                });
                            } // end else

                        }
                    }); // end ok.addClickHandler

                    cancel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                            System.out.println("cancel Click");
                            dialog.hide();
                            tbname.setText(null);
                            tbbeschr.setText(null);
                        }
                    }); // end cancel.addClickHandler

                } // end if(!(cellindex) && !(rowindex) =0 )

            } // end public void OnClick()
        }); // end t.addClickHandler
    } // end onModuleLoad(}

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot my post. :D Merry Christmas. Thank you, now it is working correctly. I tried it something like you did it (sry, forgot to tell, what I've done), but it was wrong (run's only one time). And yes, I'm very new to GWT. Another question: which database is a good way to save and load the values? Thank you for your help and I wish you a good new year. :)

Comment: EDIT: But now is the problem, that the else (shows a dialog, when all textBoxes are empty) will not work correctly. It is getting the values from the Boxes before the if...