# GWT - Unexpected firing of CellList's SelectionChangeEvent

Tags: events, gwt, celllist

I have two buttons "Next element" and "Previous element" and some custom widget containing CellList.
On button clicks I call to my widget's method which changeselection in CellList by calling it's SelectionModel:

```
selectionModel.setSelected(value, true);
```

When I refresh CellList's contents, the buttons work just fine, but when I select element in list by clicking on it, this behavior happens:
For example, I have elements {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..} on the list. I click on element 1, then press "Next element" button two times. These SelectionChangeEvent occurs:

1. Change selection from 1 -> 2 (on first button press)
2. 2 -> 3 (on second press)
3. 3 -> 1

But after step 2 if I press "Previous" it correctly go back to element 1. So element that I clicked with mouse doesn't let selection go more than 1 step around it.
I have no idea where the third event is coming from. My only guess is that manual selection event continues pending after firing, but I don't know how to check that.
Anybody knows the reason of this problem?

upd:
I found confirmation that selection by clicking event continues to hanging there somewhere in the EventBus: when I change search filters I access SelectionModel the same way as on button clicks and set selection to first element. But if there was user click on CellList before that the same thing happens: first, selection changes to 0, second, it goes back to previously selected if new selection of data contains that element.

upd (for Ümit's question):

```
nextButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      /* Omitting checks that there are elements on the list,
         some element is selected and isn't last */
      T value = dataProvider.getList().get(currentIndex() + 1);
      singleSelectionModel.setSelected(value, true);
      singleSelectionModel.isSelected(value);
      Element rowElement = cellList.getRowElement(index);
      rowElement.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

upd: **Found what was causing this problem:** http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6310

Comment: post the code of your `ClickCallHandler` for "Next element" and "previous element"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to use HandlerRegistration. So multiple click event is not called.

Refer to:

[GWT Handler Registratin](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/event/shared/HandlerRegistration.html)

and

[related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715034/gwt-problem-with-handlerregistration)

Comment: Don't know what are you talking about. There are click handlers attached to buttons to change my widget's state. But my question is, where that 3rd event could come from?

Comment: How are you adding the eventHandler. The possible case could be.. first you add a eventHandler (say eHandler1) for first press, later on another press.. you add another eventHandler (say eHandler2). But the first eHandler1 seems not be cleared out. So two eventHandlers are getting called in second click.

You can confirm it is so, by clicking it three time.. does it goes 3 times?

Comment: That's not the case.
Before clicking on the element of CellList itself functionality of buttons works fine, but on click it seems that selection event (let's call it manualSelect) doesn't go from EventBus correctly, and when after that I call it's SelectionModel to change current selection, manualSelect fires again, returning selection to one that I clicked with the mouse.
Even if I'm right about EventBus I have no clue why manualSelect isn't fired on first attempt to call SelectionModel, but on second time.